# Is it possible to override map aliases in SystemJS config?

Tags: javascript, systemjs

**Scenario**

I'm working with a library of code that has a specific namespace. But part of the codebase is local and several other parts are npm modules, that all fall under that same namespace.

**Problem**

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to 'override' a map alias within the SystemJS config? The problem i have is that i'd like to declare a base alias for the local version of the library and then more specific map aliases for the npm modules.

**Attempt 1**

Initially i thought it may be possible to do this:

```
{
    bundles: {
        'bx/google/drive': ['bx/google/drive/files', 'bx/google/drive/permissions', 'bx/google/drive/query']
    },
    map: {
        'bx/': '/src/bx',
        'bx/google/core': 'node_modules/bx.google.core/bundles/bx.google.core.js',
        'bx/google/drive': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
        'bx/google/analytics': 'node_modules/bx.google.analytics/bundles/bx.google.analytics.js',
        'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        bx: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
}
```

But this only uses the initial `bx/` alias to resolve any imports found starting with that path, so fails to load any of the `bx` npm module code.

**Attempt 2**

I thought i may be able to define all of the `bx` 'sub' modules using a package map:

```
System.config({
    bundles: {
        'bx/google/drive': ['bx/google/drive/files', 'bx/google/drive/permissions', 'bx/google/drive/query']
    },
    map: {
        'bx': '/src/bx',
        'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        bx: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            map: {
                './google/core': 'node_modules/bx.google.core/bundles/bx.google.core.js',
                './google/drive': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
                './google/drive/files': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
                './google/drive/permissions': 'node_modules/cx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
                './google/drive/query': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
                './google/analytics': 'node_modules/bx.google.analytics/bundles/bx.google.analytics.js'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This fails, but not in the same way, as no errors are thrown until the imported classes are used, as any `bx` Class imported from the npm module is `undefined`. (I also had to explicitly define all the bundle import paths).

**Solution so far**

The only way i've found so far is to remove the `bx/` definition from the map and explicitly list every single map alias and package for code within `/src/bx/`. i.e

```
{
    bundles: {
        'bx/google/drive': ['bx/google/drive/files', 'bx/google/drive/permissions', 'bx/google/drive/query']
    },
    map: {
        'bx/forms': '/src/bx/forms',
        'bx/preload': '/src/bx/preload',
        'bx/cache': '/src/bx/cache',
        /* etc */
        'bx/google/core': 'node_modules/bx.google.core/bundles/bx.google.core.js',
        'bx/google/drive': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
        'bx/google/analytics': 'node_modules/bx.google.analytics/bundles/bx.google.analytics.js',
        'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        'bx/forms': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'bx/preload': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'bx/cache': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
}
```

Which is not really ideal.

**Question**

So what i'd like to know, is whether it's possible to define a 'base' map alias for the local `bx/` code (`bx: 'src/bx'`) and then override that with more specific map aliases for the `bx` npm modules?

---

** Update **

Adding the base `bx/` to `paths` removes the need to list all `bx` paths individually as unique values in `maps`, but they still need to be listed individually in `packages`.

```
{
    bundles: {
        'bx/google/drive': ['bx/google/drive/files', 'bx/google/drive/permissions', 'bx/google/drive/query']
    },
    paths: {
        'bx/': '/src/bx'
    },
    map: {
        'bx/google/core': 'node_modules/bx.google.core/bundles/bx.google.core.js',
        'bx/google/drive': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
        'bx/google/analytics': 'node_modules/bx.google.analytics/bundles/bx.google.analytics.js',
        'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        'bx/forms': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'bx/preload': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'bx/cache': {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to revisit this after gaining a better understanding of SystemJs and spent quite a lot of time trying different combinations to solve the issue.

After much head scratching, i annoyingly found that **Attempt 1** required just one small change in order for this to work (unless the fact this now works was due to a systemjs update?)

Changing the `map` value for `bx` from:

`'bx/': '/src/bx'`

to:

`'bx': '/src/bx',`

solved the original problem.

```
{
    bundles: {
        'bx/google/drive': ['bx/google/drive/files', 'bx/google/drive/permissions', 'bx/google/drive/query']
    },
    map: {
        'bx': '/src/bx',
        'bx/google/core': 'node_modules/bx.google.core/bundles/bx.google.core.js',
        'bx/google/drive': 'node_modules/bx.google.drive/bundles/bx.google.drive.js',
        'bx/google/analytics': 'node_modules/bx.google.analytics/bundles/bx.google.analytics.js',
        'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'systemjs': 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js'
    },
    packages: {
        bx: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Global map doesn't chain with global map, but it does chain with paths.

You could try defining `bx/` as a path:

```
System.config({ paths: { 'bx/': 'path/to/bx/' } })
```

And then use map config for individual entries that are exceptions to this rule:

```
System.config({ map: { 'bx/y': 'custom/location' } })
```

Comment: Thanks Guy, i've updated my post. That removes the need to add all local `bx/` paths individually to `map`, but fails if they're not all still listed individually in `packages`